# How to Render API result to a Element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, reactjs, web-applications

In the function handleExampleClick, I want to update App-menuViewer with the results of the `console.log(res.body.matches[i].id);`. Right now I am logging the information to the console. But I want the information to actually update the app-menuviewer. How can I do this? repo is here if you need to see more information: https://github.com/KanteLabs/Whats-Cookin/

```
function handleCookbookClick() {
    ReactDOM.render(
  <Cookbook />,
  document.getElementById('App-menuViewer')
);}


function handleExampleClick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
  request
  .get(searchRecipes)
  .query({ q: searchParameters2 }) // query string
  .type('json')
  .end(function(err, res){
    for(var i = 0; i < res.body.matches.length;i++){
      console.log(res.body.matches[i].id);
    }
  }),
    document.getElementById('App-menuViewer')
);}



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h2>"What's Cookin'"</h2>
      <input className="searchBox" placeholder="search something"/>
            <button onClick={handleExampleClick}>Example</button>
    </div>      
    <div id="App-menu">
            <button onClick={handleCookbookClick}>Cookbook</button>
            <button>Recommendations</button>
            <button>Shopping List</button>
            <button>Search Options</button>
    </div>
        <div id="App-menuViewer"></div>
        <div className="App-SearchResults">
          <p>{ingredients}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: store your value on a variable and use `innerHTML` to populate the value on the element

Comment: so would the code be like this? `document.getElementById('App-menuViewer').innerHTML(recipeName)`

Comment: No - it should be like this `document.getElementById('App-menuViewer').innerHTML = recipeName;`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked and solved the issue that I was happening.

Comment: Do you mind me putting this as an answer and accept it? :)

Comment: Yeah go ahead .

Comment: @AmidouKante It work but it's not the React way to do that, you don't have to modify the DOM by yourself but just let React do the rendering. You can update your component state with the result of the request and the view will be refreshed. I made you a simple example here : http://www.webpackbin.com/41uhF9kUG

Comment: @Freez I am attempting to use your code if it is the react way. I'm not too familiar with promises. But is there a way to modify this code so that it takes a users input from a search box and then searches for that result using an AJAX call and returning the result in the DOM? I already figured out how to do the search but I can't figure out how to exactly implement it.

Comment: You don't have to use promises, you can keep your code with `.end(function(err, res){ ... }`, but you have to modify the component state. Look at my exemple, I modify the DOM with asynchronous data. Try to do the same with your server data. It's an other philosophy than access/modify the DOM but just declare the DOM you want to be rendered according to the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this as an answer as agreed by the owner :)

**Answer**

Store your value in a variable and use innerHTML to populate the value on the element

**Example**

```
var recipeName = "";


....
.end(function(err, res){
 for(var i = 0; i < res.body.matches.length;i++){
    recipeName += res.body.matches[i].id; //assuming that its a string value      
 }
}),

document.getElementById('App-menuViewer').innerHTML = recipeName;

....
```